# Left-wards greedyness for a group REGEX

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

Next regex says any optional group of 1 to 3 digits plus any optional group of 4 non-whitespaced chars.

```
^([\d]{1,3})?(\S{4})?$
```

My problem is that if I input  444EEE, Java matches it as 44 + 4EEE, instead of, matching first the first group as 444 and exiting because the trailing EEE is not made of 4 chars. So how can I avoid the left-wards greediness of the last group, so the second last consumes first. Is it "?+"

Thank you

Comment: One question: Is `1234` a valid match? Is the empty string valid? The rules are not really well-defined yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("(\\d{0,3}+)(\\S{4})");
```

The extra `+` after the `{0,3}` quantifier tells the regex engine not to backtrack into the first group (a so-called [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)).

Comment: add `?` to groups because from what i see in OP question they are optional

Comment: There's a terminological point worth making here: the problem is not about *greediness* (which determines what order matches are considered in) but about making some matches not be considered at all.

Comment: @Pshemo: The first group *is* sort of optional since it allows `0` digits. However, you're right - if the string is `1234`, this regex wouldn't pass it.